# Why my C program unexpectedly terminates when using floor and ceil and rounding functions?

Tags: c

My project is to create a Calculator, which includes some rounding functions like:

Normal rounding, Floor, and ceiling.

They appear in the program like this:

1. round(x)
2. ceil(x)
3. floor(x)

Here's the code of that menu:

```
    else if (user_input == 3){      /*Rounding Operations*/
    instructions_Rounding();
    scanf("%d",user_input);
    while(user_input!=4){
        if(user_input==1){              /*For round(x)*/
            printf("\nEnter a number to round it: ");
            scanf("%lf",&num1);
            double rnd;
            rnd = num1+0.5;
            result = floor(rnd);
            printf("\nResult is %f", result);
            user_input=4;

        else if(user_input==2){         /*For ceil(x)*/
            printf("\nEnter a number: ");
            scanf("%lf",&num1);
            result = ceil(num1);
            printf("\nResult is %f", result);
            user_input=4;
        }

        else if(user_input==3){         /*For floor(x)*/
            printf("\nEnter a number: ");
            scanf("%lf",&num1);
            result = floor(num1);
            printf("\nResult is %f",result);
            user_input=4;

        }

    }

}
```

Note: This loop can  be ended by setting user_input to 4, but this loop is inside a bigger loop that can be ended by setting it to 5. I don't know how this might help but I thought it might be the cause of something and it might be worth mentioning.

Anyway, the prorgam runs flawlessly except when I choose anything from this menu, it gives me an error like this:

http://oi44.tinypic.com/2gwdssy.jpg

I really don't see anything wrong with my code. It used to work good before but only when I had a problem with the menus, needed a while to figure how to return to the main menu after each operation instead of getting stuck in an infinite loop. But only when I fixed it did this happen. Not sure why.

Can someone tell me if anything is wrong with this code? Is it normal for it to act this way?

Oh, and I tested it on 3 different computers so it's not a problem from my computer.

Comment: Do you `#include <math.h>`?

Comment: Note: The error found by Mark hints to a flaw in the code logic.  E.g. if `user_input` is anything but 1,2,3,4, the while loop will loop forever.  Suggest adding a `else user_input=4;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
scanf("%d",user_input);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%d",&user_input);
```

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler didn't emit a warning for this (or maybe the OP didn't have warnings enabled?).

Comment: Oh my god. I feel so stupid right now, damn.
Thanks a lot! It's funny when the error is something this small. And the compiler didn't even warn or give an error.

Comment: @kaizoku:  No need to feel stupid; it's easy to miss those things.  But, yes, usually the compiler should help with those.  You might check your settings.  Add -Wall if using gcc or /W3 if an MS compiler (although I did not test just now to see if that would help ... but it should).